# How to loop through series to produce a data frame and add columns to it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of series that I want to stack, make a dataframe, and add other series to that dataframe going through the same process.

I have done it step by step in jupyter notebook but when I try to make a for statement and a function to do what i can do (step-wise) in jupyter notebook  the program fails giving me an error.

**The code**:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'sum':[140.0, 45.0, 17907.0], 'mean':[35.00, 11.25, 4476.75],'count':[4, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['age', 'offspring', 'total_pop'])
data2 = {'sum':[14.0, 46.0, 14607.0], 'mean':[345.00, 121.25, 5476.75], 'count':[2, 2, 2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['age', 'offspring', 'total_pop'])
data3 = {'sum':[528.0, 15.0, 1407.0], 'mean':[700.00, 552.25, 4156.75], 'count':[3, 3, 3]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, index=['age', 'offspring', 'total_pop'])

def dosomething(df):
        stacked = df.stack()
        df = pd.Series(stacked)
        df.to_frame()
        dfd = pd.DataFrame(df)
        df = df.join(dfd)
        print(dfd)

total_df = [(df1), (df2), (df3,)]

for n in range(0, len(total_df)):
        total_df[n] = dosomething(total_df[n])
```

**Expected**:

```
                      1         2        3
age       sum      140.00     14.00   528.00
          mean      35.00    345.00   700.00
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
offspring sum       45.00     46.00    15.00
          mean      11.25    121.25   552.25
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
total_pop sum    17907.00  14607.00  1407.00
          mean    4476.75   5476.75  4156.75
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
```

**Actual error**:

> ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `concat`:

```
dfs = [df,df2, df3]
pd.concat([df.stack() for df in dfs], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                        0         1        2
age       sum      140.00     14.00   528.00
          mean      35.00    345.00   700.00
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
offspring sum       45.00     46.00    15.00
          mean      11.25    121.25   552.25
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
total_pop sum    17907.00  14607.00  1407.00
          mean    4476.75   5476.75  4156.75
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the loop this will work:

```py
# stack dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns=[1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.stack(), columns=[2])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3.stack(), columns=[3])

#join on index
final_df = df.join(df2).join(df3)
```

If you need to use a loop you could do:

```py
# stack first df
final_df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns=[1])
# loop through other dfs
for n, next_df in {2: df2, 3: df3}.items():
    next_df = pd.DataFrame(next_df.stack(), columns=[n])
    final_df = final_df.join(next_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pd.concat` with option `keys` to do a single `stack` on the final `df` instead of each `stack` per `df`

```
df_list = [df, df2, df3]
pd.concat(df_list, keys=range(len(df_list)), axis=1).stack()

Out[127]:
                        0         1        2
age       sum      140.00     14.00   528.00
          mean      35.00    345.00   700.00
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
offspring sum       45.00     46.00    15.00
          mean      11.25    121.25   552.25
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
total_pop sum    17907.00  14607.00  1407.00
          mean    4476.75   5476.75  4156.75
          count      4.00      2.00     3.00
```